# Applying Middleware-like mechanism to Resolvers' Queries and Mutations

Tags: express, nestjs

I'm building a GraphQL API using Nest framework and I'm trying to implement 3rd party express middlewares ([express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) and [express-slow-down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-slow-down)) into some queries and mutations.

The problem is all graphql mutations and queries use the same endpoint, so I can't explicitly tell to which query or mutations shall the middleware be applied, because you can only do that using route's path (which is the same across the API).

```js
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common'
import * as rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit'
import * as RedisStore from 'rate-limit-redis'
import { RedisClient } from 'redis'

@Module({
    providers: [],
    exports: [],
})
export default class SecurityModule implements NestModule
{

    constructor(protected readonly redisClient: RedisClient) 
    {

    }

    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) 
    {

        consumer.apply(
            new rateLimit({
                max:      300,
                windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
                store:    new RedisStore({ client: this.redisClient }),
            })).forRoutes({ path: '/graphql', method: RequestMethod.ALL }) // this would apply the middleware to all queries and mutations
    }
}
```

So I tried using both guards and interceptors for that purpose, but failed miserably.

It's a fail for an obvious reason.
The `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent` is thrown.

```js
/* !!! My Interceptor would like quite identical */

import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, CanActivate } from '@nestjs/common'
import * as speedLimit from 'express-slow-down'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'

@Injectable()
export default class SpeedLimitGuard implements CanActivate 
{

    constructor(
        protected readonly options: speedLimit.Options,
        ) {
    }

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {

        const { req, res }: { req: Request, res: Response } = context.getArgs()[2]

        speedLimit({ ...this.options })(req, res, req.next)

        return true
    }
}
```

```js
import { NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, Injectable, INestApplication, INestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import * as speedLimit from 'express-slow-down'
// import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { ApplicationReferenceHost } from '@nestjs/core'
import { RedisClient } from 'redis'
import * as RedisStore from 'rate-limit-redis'

@Injectable()
export default class SpeedLimitInterceptor implements NestInterceptor 
{

    constructor(private readonly appRefHost: ApplicationReferenceHost,
        private readonly redisClient: RedisClient, ) 
    {}

    intercept<T>(context: ExecutionContext, call$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> 
    {

        // const { req: request, res: response }: { req: Request, res: Response } = context.getArgs()[2]

        const httpServer = this.appRefHost.applicationRef

        const app: INestApplication & INestExpressApplication = httpServer.getInstance()

        app.use(speedLimit({
            delayAfter: 1,
            store:      new RedisStore({
                prefix: 'test_',
                client: this.redisClient,
            }),
        }))

        app.use((req, res, next) => {
            console.log('is middleware triggered', { req, res })
            next()
        })

        return call$
    }
}
```

Is there any way to apply a 3rd party express middleware to a GraphQL Mutation/Query explicitly?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of your interceptor? That would be the correct type of Nest component to use to solve this problem

Comment: @JesseCarter I included the incerptor in my post edit. It's not working and I understand why. I just can't get my head around how it should be implemented properly.

Comment: I think the middlewares added in the interceptor never get triggered, because - I suspect - it's already too late in the application lifecycle to register a middleware, but I can't be sure.

Comment: From what I know the application lifecycle is:
Middlewares -> Guards -> Interceptors -> Pipes
So registering middlewares in an interceptor looks like a bad idea.

Comment: Middlewares are literally just a function that run before your actual handler, in that sense Interceptors are basically just another form of middleware. Your issue is that you're trying to *register the middleware* with the app in your Interceptor which is the wrong approach. You could just be invoking it instead

Answer (score 2):

So from the bottom, guards are working, because I'm the living human bean that can prove it:

```js
    @Query('getHome')
    @UseGuards(GraphqlGuard)
    async findOneById(@Args('id') id: string): Promise<HomeEntity> {
        return await this.homeService.findOneById(id);
    }
```

and it's just working.

This is `GraphqlGuard.ts`

```js
import {ExecutionContext, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {GqlExecutionContext} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import {AuthGuard} from '@nestjs/passport';
import {ExecutionContextHost} from '@nestjs/core/helpers/execution-context.host';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GraphqlGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const {req} = ctx.getContext();
        return super.canActivate(new ExecutionContextHost([req]));
    }
}
```

But to live with context, you have to make it works for you, so, wherever you're passing graphql config, there is an context `callback`, and for me it looks like this:

```js
            context: (context) => {
                let req = context.req;
                if (context.connection) {
                    req = context.connection.context.req;
                }
                return {req};
            }
```

I'm checking here connection for context from websocket. Im using global interceptors so, they're working like a charm. But you still can use `@UseInterceptors(SomeInterceptor)` decorator and it also works. And btw Middlewares, at the end, I doesn't need any of them guards, pipes, validators and interceptors for me was quite enough.

Regards.

Comment: It's not explaining how to implement 3rd party libraries like `express-speed-down` or `express-rate-limit` in an interceptor,